# Can I use jquery datapicker as a readonly calendar? not "picker"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

My requirement is simple: I have a sharepoint list with an events list.
I want to use the jquery calendar to show a tooltip in a highlighted day, when there is an event that day.

My intention is not to use it in a textbox for input. just read only.

If this is possible, what should I change in the jquery calendar config?

thx

Comment: -2 lol, and no comment, at least post the reason its a 100% valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an inline datepicker :)

```js
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="datepicker"></div>
```